# spring mvc: how to add custom annotion on parameters to controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

This is my controller class:

```
@Component
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class MyController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = {"test"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String test(@MyAnnotation String myValue)
    {
        return "myValue:"+myValue;
    }
}
```

Moreover, below is my interceptor class:

```
public class MyInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor
{
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception
    {
        MyAnnotation annotation = ((HandlerMethod)handler).getMethod().getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
        // TODO
    }
    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception
    {
    }
    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception e) throws Exception
    {
    }
}
```

if I want myValue to be "test", then how to implement the custom annotation @MyAnnotation? what to do in class MyInterceptor

Comment: Have a look at [@RequestParam](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) and [@ModelAttribute](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html) which should suffice for most of the use case; unless you have something specific

Comment: If I change @ MyAnnotation from ElementType.PARAMETER to ElementType.METHOD, and I use @ ModelAttribute, and I want to dynamically set myValue in interceptor class, how to do?

Comment: Your current approach is flawed and will not work. You need a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` implementation for your custom annotation.

Comment: I used to try it, but it doesn't work. seems HandlerMethodArgumentResolver is deprecated. could you please give a step-by-step example of it ?

Comment: No it isn't, if it doesn't work you did something wrong.